# How can I show an confirmation message in Actionscript 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

How can I show an confirmation message in Actionscript 3 ?

I use Adobe Flex 3 and as3 for Air application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Alert.show("Are you sure?", "Title",
    mx.controls.Alert.YES | mx.controls.Alert.NO, this, alertEventHandler);
```

Then create an `alertEventHandler` with the following code:

```
function alertEventHandler(event:CloseEvent):void {
    if(event.detail == Alert.YES) {
        // pressed yes.
    }
}
```

Or check out a custom Dialog class: http://fatal-exception.co.uk/blog/?p=69

Comment: I get this error :
1119: Access of possibly undefined property No through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Alert.html, correct. Sorry for typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alert class for that.

```
Alert.show(...);
```